# MS SQL SSRS. I have Page Setup button in BIDS designer but users dont have it in the Reports Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

There are quite a few buttons in BIDS (VS2008) when I preview a report but in the Report Manager what the users can see - there is only Export button.

I would like at least have Page Setup button so the user can manage the export.

If for instance I want to export to PDF on landscape A3 - what do I do?

*P.S. the SSRS and DB are **MS SQL 2008**. The security is huge problem as I have to request every little thing through managers and then chaise it for hours with the admins.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting Services (2000/2005/2008/2008 R2) does not provide a method for modifying the PageSize and Margins sizes based on expressions which would be a requirement to achieve the functionality you are requesting when using the Export feature.  The print button does allow users to modify the orientation and margins, but not much else.

You can create a separate render extension that changes the orientation [according to this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx).  I've never tried it, but it looks promising.

Comment: why Visual Studio can do that stuff (and more) and Report Manager cant ?

Comment: Report manager does allow changing the margins and orientation with the print button. I just tested this and it worked exactly like BIDS.  @Adolf Garlic included a link that shows the print options for a user in Report Manager.  Just make certain the Print Option is enabled in the server configuration.  The ReportServer.dbo.ConfigurationInfo table should have a value of true for the EnableClientPrinting row for users to have the print button in Report Manager.

Comment: the question is not about print. I want users to change the report view and hence be able to export into PDF with user-defined page setup (not programmatically hardcoded by a developer)...

Comment: Ouch.  That would only seem possible if the PageSize and Margins supported expressions -- which they don't.

Comment: I came across an article that indicates you can create custom render extensions and they show how to make the standard TIF export default to portrait or landscape based on which one you select.  I updated the answer with a link to the MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

Other info: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/client-side-printing-silent-deployment-of-rsclientPrint.aspx